# What is the number of invertible functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5\}^{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}$ such that $f(x)\neq x\forall x?$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

So basically I thought the question was just asking for derangements of the function, which is $5!(\frac {1}{2}-\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{20} - \frac{1}{120}) = 45$. However the answer given is $44$, and this is also checked by a program I wrote. So I wonder wheres the problem in my work?

Comment: $4!=24$, not $20$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct...the error is in the arithmetic.  $4!=24$ and not $20$.  It's an odd coincidence that your expression even comes out an integer!

Answer (score 1):

That is because $4!=24$ and not $20$. Hence the required expression becomes  $5!(\frac {1}{2} - \frac {1}{6} +\frac {1}{24} - \frac {1}{120}) =44$ which is the answer.